# Finding the slope of the line normal to the graph at a given point

Tags: calculus, derivatives, slope

> **My Problem:** What is the slope of the line normal to the graph of $f(x) = e^x-x^e-e$ at the point where the graph crosses the $x$-axis?
>
> - a. $-0.288$
> - b. $-0.110$
> - c. $3.471$
> - d. $9.106$

I found that $f(x)$ crosses the $x$ axis at $3.471$, but is that the answer? Do I have to plug it back into the equation? Thank you!

Comment: This is definitively not the searched answer, you must compute the slope at this point and then the slope of the normal line

Answer (score 0):

Recall: the equation of the line at $(x^*,y^*)$ for a function $f$ can be given by the point-slope form:

$$y - y^* = f'(x^*) \cdot (x - x^*)$$

(analogous to the $y=mx+b$ form for linear equations). The point where $f$ crosses the $x$ axis is a point where $y^* = 0$, and you found $x^* \approx 3.471$. All that remains for this part is to find $f'$ and then plug in everything as necessary above.

Shift it into the $y = mx+b$ form, then, where $m$ will be the slope of the tangent line at that point.

---

From there, recall that the "normal" line is just a line perpendicular to the given line. Suppose we have two lines,

$$y_1 = m_1 x + b_1 \;\;\;\;\; y_2 = m_2 x + b_2$$

If $y_2$ is perpendicular to $y_1$, then

$$m_2 = - \frac{1}{m_1}$$

i.e. the slopes of perpendicular lines are negative reciprocals of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: We get by the sum and the power rule $$f'(x)={{\rm e}^{x}}-{\frac {{x}^{{\rm e}}{\rm e}}{x}}$$ Can you proceed?